# Rcpp integrated with R package: Documentation of CPP code objects

Tags: r, package, travis-ci, rcpp

I have been developing a package with Rcpp for C++ integration. I used RcppExport to make the functions return SEXP objects.

The issue is travis-ci seems to give warnings telling that there are undocumented code objects. (These are cpp functions). However I do not want users to directly access those functions as well.

How can I resolve this issue? How can I document these functions as well?

Comment: Are you using Rcpp C++ roxygen comments?

Comment: No. I haven't used that. Will adding roxygen comments help to generate the documentation?

Comment: Rcpp roxygen comment is prefixed by `//'` instead of `#'`

Comment: Roxygen is an _option_ you can use but you are _not forced_ to use it.  You need to learn a bit more about packages -- but yes, with Roxygen you _can_ content autotransfered from .cpp to .R to .Rd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have an elementary misunderstanding here.

If your `NAMESPACE` contains a wildcard 'export all' *a la* `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` then each global symbol is exported *and per R standards that are clearly documented* needs a help entry.

One easy fix is NOT to export everything and just write documentation for what you want exported.  We sometimes do that and call the Rcpp function something like `foo_impl` and then have R functions `foo` (with documentation) call `foo_impl`.   In that case you would just export `foo` and all is good.

In short, you are confused about *R packages* and not so much *Rcpp*.  I would recommend downloading the *sources* of a few (small) Rcpp packages to get a feel for what they do.

Comment: To export desired functions within the _roxygen2_ paradigm use `#' @export` for R code and `//' @export` for cpp.

Comment: That again is an _option_ that I (personally) recommend against but that dislike may just be me.  Your mileage may vary, and ten word recommendation may understate all available choice you have.

Comment: I can _sense_ a new question arising after removing the `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` since roxygen2 still controls the namespace. Proactivity.

Comment: It doesn't. It is a misdesign. It offers three pieces of functionality, but I only use one (ie `R -> Rd`) and I never ever let it touch my `DESCRIPTION` or `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you very much. Yes that solves the problem. I'll go through a few examples to see how it's properly implemented. :D